# How to take existing input values, random them and place it back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons one for **Reset** input fields and other for **Random** values. I have following javascript code to reset input fields to blank and it's working fine.

```
    $(".reset").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
    });
```

Now I want to take all values from the input field, random them and place it back. On every click, numbers will be different.

Here is the HTML for input fields.

```
    <input type="text" name="seed[]" value="1" id="name" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="seed[]" value="2" id="name" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="seed[]" value="3" id="name" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="seed[]" value="4" id="name" class="form-control">
```

[image: Seeding]

Comment: Then use `Math.random()` to get a random float value 0-1 and use it to generate a value for the inputs.

Comment: You can't reuse the same ID, IDs are meant to be unique.

Comment: Open your browser console and type `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` and see what you get, and experiment!

Comment: @MusaButt What have you tried to tackle the issue yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

$(".random").click(function() {
    let vals = $("input[name='seed[]'], textarea").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
    vals = shuffle(vals);
    $.each($("input[name='seed[]'], textarea"), function(i,val){
        $(this).val(vals[i]);
    })
    console.log(vals)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="1" id="name" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="seed[]" value="2" id="name" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="seed[]" value="3" id="name" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="seed[]" value="4" id="name" class="form-control">
<button class="random">random</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` generates a random float in the range `[0, 1)`. `Math.floor(Math.random() * n)` will give you an integer in the range `[0, n-1]`. Use this to shuffle the values. In general, to fully randomize `n` values in-place and simply, iterate and swap each value `i` with a random value taken from `[i, n]`:

```js
let sorted = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let shuffled = [...sorted];
for (let i = 0; i < shuffled.length; i++) {
  let randIndex = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (shuffled.length - i));
  let t = shuffled[randIndex];
  shuffled[randIndex] = shuffled[i];
  shuffled[i] = t;
}

console.log(shuffled);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the the IDs of your input elements should be unique.

```
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="1" id="nameA" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="2" id="nameB" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="3" id="nameC" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="4" id="nameD" class="form-control">
```

Using the function `document.getElementsByTagName("input")`, you get an array of all input text fields.
Now simply loop over that array to get the values of each input element and store it in a temporary array. After that randomize the elements inside this array and finally assign each input element a value out of this array.

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var values = [];

for (var a = 0; a < list.length; a++) {
  values.push(list[a].value);
}
values.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random()
});

for (var a = 0; a < list.length; a++) {
  list[a].value = values[a];
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="1" id="nameA" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="2" id="nameB" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="3" id="nameC" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="4" id="nameD" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying for the one-liner:

```
$.each($("input[type='text']").map((index, element) => $(element).val()).get().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5), (i, value) => { $("input[type='text']").eq(i).val(value); });
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
$(".click").click(() => {
  $.each($("input[type='text']").map((index, element) => $(element).val()).get().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5), (i, value) => { $("input[type='text']").eq(i).val(value); });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.slim.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="1" id="nameA" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="2" id="nameB" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="3" id="nameC" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="seed[]" value="4" id="nameD" class="form-control">

<a class="click" href="#">Click me</a>
```

**Update:** As mentioned in the comments by @junvar this is indeed not truly random shuffle of the array. If one really needs truly randomisation this could be expanded to make use of something like the [Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) which has been mentioned in other answers:

```
function shuffle(a) {
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a;
}

$.each(shuffle($("input[type='text']").map((index, element) => $(element).val()).get()), (i, value) => { $("input[type='text']").eq(i).val(value); });
```

Comment: Sometimes it leaves the input field blank. I want all input filled each time I click

Comment: You should check if the selector (i.e. the `input[type='text']`) is exactly matching what you want. My guess is that it's filling some other input on your page

Comment: This is inaccurate. `array.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)` may be succinct, but it's not fully random. For example, given `array = [1, 2, 3]`, 37% of the results after shuffling will be `[1, 2, 3]`, whereas only 6% will be `[1, 3, 2]`!

Comment: @junvar yes you are right, I am aware, I was aiming for the one-liner here. I will update the answer to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

This one can be simply done using plain javascript.
I have created a sample plunker
[here](https://embed.plnkr.co/efg6gAG3l4s04HU8Bjq0/)